# Laravel API routes and Controller variable

Tags: laravel, api, routes

I'm a new user of Laravel, and i'm a bit confused with Laravel route API and the name of variable in the controller.
Here an example to explain :
An API route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('cepage', CepageController::class);
});
```

For a PUT or PATCH, i have this function in the CepageController :

```
public function update(Request $request, Cepage $cepage)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'libelle' => 'required',
            'abrege' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return $this->sendError($validator->errors());
        }

        $cepage->libelle = $input['libelle'];
        $cepage->abrege = $input['abrege'];
        $cepage->save();

        return $this->sendResponse(new CepageResource($cepage), 'Cépage mis à jour');
    }
```

If you see my route name "cepage" have the same name of the $cepage variable of the function declaration in the controller, Laravel update the record in the database.

If they are no identical, Laravel create a new record in the database.

Why they need to be exactly the same ?

I think i miss something in the documenation of Laravel.

Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be the same, for laravel to know what object does he needs to create for us.

`Route::resource` does a few routes for you, with the base url give into it (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

So once you have defined Route::resource('cepage', CepageController::class)
You will have the following routes defined:

- Verb URI Action  Route Name
- GET  /cepage CepageController@index cepage.index
- GET /cepage/create  CepageController@create cepage.create
- POST    /cepage CepageController@store  cepage.store
- GET /cepage/{cepage_id} CepageController@show   cepage.show
- GET /cepage/{cepage_id}/edit    CepageController@edit   cepage.edit
- PUT/PATCH   /cepage/{cepage_id} CepageController@update cepage.update
- DELETE  /cepage/{cepage_id} CepageController@destroy    cepage.destroy

And in the controller you need to follow the naming, because in the url you have only ids of the object. But if you follow the naming, laravel will fetch the object for you by its id. See:

```
public function update(Request $request, $cepage_id)
{
   $cepage = Cepage::find($cepage_id);
   //here you have to fetch the object for yourself to access it
}
public function update(Request $request, Cepage $cepage)
{
   //here you can already access $cepage variable
}
```